# Can ETL be used with Atmel Studio?

Tags: c++, stl, arm, embedded, atmelstudio

The [Embedded Template Library](https://www.etlcpp.com/) provides the data structures of the STL without using dynamic allocation, to be used in embedded development.

I'm experimenting with the ATSAMD21 in Atmel Studio, and cannot use dynamic allocation. Therefore I tried the ETL, but it gives me the same errors I get when I'm trying to use STL:

```
Error       ld returned 1 exit status
Error       undefined reference to `_exit'
Error       undefined reference to `_close'
Error       undefined reference to `_fstat'
Error       undefined reference to `_isatty'
Error       undefined reference to `_lseek'
Error       undefined reference to `_read'
Error       undefined reference to `_sbrk'
Error       undefined reference to `_kill'
Error       undefined reference to `_getpid'
Error       undefined reference to `_write'
```

As far as I know, these errors mean that a wrong target architecture was selected for the compiler. However, that shouldn't be the case, because my program worked just fine before I defined a single ETL structure. Also, the ETL is composed of just a bunch of header files.

My guess was that ETL uses code from STL, and the gnu compiler included in Atmel Studio can't handle it. (but they why did they even include STL if it's completely unusable?)

However, ETL can supposedly be used [even without STL](https://www.etlcpp.com/no_stl.html).

So I defined `#define ETL_NO_STL` in my project, but I still get the same errors.

**new**

It seems to be working correctly in "release" mode, these errors only appear in "debug".

The differences between debug and release don't indicate me any use of STL in one, versus the other:

Debug:

> "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\arm\arm-gnu-toolchain\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"
> -mthumb -D__SAMD21J18A__ -DDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\SAMD21_DFP\1.2.276\samd21a\include"
> -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\arm\CMSIS\4.2.0\CMSIS\Include"  -O1
> -ffunction-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -mlong-calls -g3 -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -c -MD -MP -MF "main.d" -MT"main.d" -MT"main.o"   -o "main.o" ".././main.cpp"

Release:

> "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\arm\arm-gnu-toolchain\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"
> -mthumb -D__SAMD21J18A__ -DNDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\SAMD21_DFP\1.2.276\samd21a\include"
> -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\arm\CMSIS\4.2.0\CMSIS\Include"  -O1
> -ffunction-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -mlong-calls -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -c -MD -MP -MF "main.d" -MT"main.d" -MT"main.o"   -o "main.o" ".././main.cpp"

The only other difference is that the debug build has an extra line:
Using "RunCompilerTask" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Extensions\Application\AvrGCC.dll".

The debugging level is not the cause. Setting it to g3, g2, g1, or turning it off doesn't change anything. The difference is whether NDEBUG is there in the command. Maybe without it there are some unnecessarily POSIX consistency checks performed?

Comment: All those missing functions are POSIX system calls. Without knowing anything about ETL, have you configured it correctly? Perhaps it can't be used on systems not implementing some of the base POSIX functions? What does the documentation say? How does your configuration look like (reading the documentation you need to create a `etl_profile.h` file, please include it)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : yes, I did create the profile header, and added ETL_TARGET_DEVICE_ARM to it.

Comment: Your Cortex M0 doesn't seem to have Linux. It appears to be a microcontroller, not a PC. Thus avoid the following things: dynamic allocation, C++, POSIX, STL, PC programming.

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend not compiling Atmel bloatware ASF below C++, because that will break the whole thing. It's pretty broken to begin with, even when compiled as C. Is it possible to use Atmel Studio without  the bloatware libraries?

Comment: @Lundin  I'm not using ASF, and I'm not using dynamic allocation. And I'm not using POSIX, at least not knowingly. I've written C++ applications for this platform, they work fine.  Now I need some trees which would be a hassle to implement manually. I've chosen ETL specifically because it's not using dynamic allocation, and ETL's multimap seemed perfect for the job. I used the arduino profile, which should support the simplest of microcontrollers, but I still get the above errors.

Comment: "undefined reference to _sbrk" means that you are using a library which uses dynamic allocation. Something isn't adding up, because the library seem to assume that you are on a Linux PC. Do they have build/link instructions? For example do you compile with `-ffreestanding` (assuming gcc)?

Comment: Anyway, what's the actual problem you are trying to solve? Getting a hash map for C? Why do you need one, what's the nature of the data?

Comment: @Lundin : I already have a program which compiles and runs fine. I added the ETL, following their [setup guide](https://www.etlcpp.com/setup.html), I specify ETL_NO_STL so that it doesn't use STL, ETL claims that without STL it won't use dynamic allocation (that's the *whole point* of ETL: to have STL-like data structures without dynamic allocation). So it means that either I misunderstood something, or the compiler thinks it should build in the dynamic allocation related stuff even if it doesn't need them. I used the profile settings from their arduino example, and arduino doesn't have an OS.

Comment: @vsz Maybe you can do a file search through your libs for those hosted system functions it is whining about. Another thing to check is which compiler & CRT you are actually using. With gcc it should be the "gcc-arm-none-eabi" one and your IDE should toss in a "start-up" file part of the CRT. I don't remember how this is done in Atmel Studio.

Comment: The toolchain is \arm\arm-gnu-toolchain\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe, and all the errors come from arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m\libc.a   So it *does* try to link in the STL even if I told it not to.

Comment: Strange, the errors happen only in debug mode. In release it's fine. I'm editing this into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compromise solution can be to add the NDEBUG parameter in debug mode, while still specifying a debugging level (like -g2 or -g3)

This allows to use breakpoints and to watch the values of variables in a debugging session, the only downside seems to be that assert statements won't work, a feature much less often used in embedded development compared to other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The ETL is designed after the STL, that's true. But the STL is long gone as a library, obsolete as its contents were merged into the C++ Standard Library.

The symbols referenced are from the C Standard Library though, which is another library that's become part of the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
My solution is to disable DEBUG mode for ETL.

You need to patch etl/platforms.h file:

```
#if (defined(_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)) && !defined(ETL_DEBUG) 
  #define ETL_DEBUG  // <---- comment out this line
#endif
```